# Tensorflow - mapping images with labels

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I need the solution, that works with TPU, neither ImageDataGenerator or tf.py_function doesn't work.

My code for CPU:

```
def get_label(file_path):
    file_name = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)[-1]
    label = image_name_to_label[file_name.numpy().decode('utf-8')]
    label = tf.constant([label])
    return label
def decode_img(img):
    img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    return tf.image.resize(img, [img_height, img_width])
def process_path(file_path):
    label = tf.py_function(func=get_label, inp=[file_path], Tout=tf.int32)
    label.set_shape((1,))
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = decode_img(img)
    return img, label
```

image_name_to_label is a python dict

I don't want to convert data to tfrecords

Comment: Ok, I found the solution using .from_tensor_slice I can load images and labels simultaneously, but question about work in map function is still and what about third party augmentations?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution using .from_tensor_slice I can load images and labels simultaneously, but question about work in map function is still and what about third party augmentations?

```
def decode_img(img):
    img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    return tf.image.resize(img, [img_height, img_width])
def process_path(file_path, label):
    img = tf.io.read_file(train_path_f+file_path)
    img = decode_img(img)
    label = tf.reshape(label,[1])
    return img, label

images = imgs_files
labels = train_csv.species_cat.values
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images, labels))
dataset = dataset.map(process_path)
```